# fast and stable x * tanh(log1pexp(x)) computation

Tags: approximation, neural-networks, floating-point, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

$$f(x) = x \tanh(\log(1 + e^x))$$

The function (mish activation) can be easily implemented using a stable log1pexp without any significant loss of precision. Unfortunately, this is computationally heavy.

Is it possible to write a more direct numerically stable implementation which is faster?

Accuracy as good as `x * std::tanh(std::log1p(std::exp(x)))` would be nice. There is no strict constraints but it should be reasonably accurate for use in neural networks.

The distribution of inputs is from $[-\infty, \infty]$. It should work everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP points to a particular [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17148) of the `mish` activation function for accuracy specifications, so I had to characterize this first. That implementation uses single precision (`float`), and is stable and accurate in the positive half-plane. In the negative half-plane, because it uses `logf` instead of `log1pf`,  relative error quickly grows a $x\to-\infty$. Loss of accuracy starts around $-1$ and already at $-16.6355324$ the implementation falsely returns $0$, because $\exp(-16.6355324) = 2^{-24}$.

The same accuracy and behavior can be achieved by using a simple mathematical transformation that eliminates $\mathrm{tanh}$, and considering that GPUs typically offer a fused multiply-add (FMA) as well as a fast reciprocal, which one would want to utilize. Exemplary CUDA code looks as follows:

```c
__device__ float my_mishf (float x)
{
    float r;
    float e = expf (x);
    r = 1.0f / fmaf (fmaf (-0.5f, e, -1.0f), e, -1.0f);
    r = fmaf (r, x, x);
    return r;
}
```

As with the reference implementation pointed to by OP, this has excellent accuracy in the positive half-plane, and in the negative half-plane error increases rapidly so at $-16.6355324$ the implementation falsely returns $0$.

If there is a desire to address these accuracy issues, we can apply the following observations. For sufficiently small $x$, $f(x) = x \exp(x)$ to within floating-point accuracy. For `float` computation this holds for $x < -15$. For the interval $[-15,-1]$, we can use a rational approximation $R(x)$ to compute $f(x) := R(x)x\exp(x)$. Exemplary CUDA code looks as follows:

```c
__device__ float my_mishf (float x)
{
    float r;
    if (x >= -1.0f) {
        float e = expf (x);
        r = 1.0f / fmaf (fmaf (-0.5f, e, -1.0f), e, -1.0f);
        r = fmaf (r, x, x);
    } else {
        float eh = expf (0.5f * x);
        float p =        1.03628484e-3f;  //  0x1.0fa7e6p-10
        p = fmaf (p, x, -7.28869531e-3f); // -0x1.ddac04p-8
        p = fmaf (p, x,  3.47027816e-2f); //  0x1.1c4902p-5
        p = fmaf (p, x, -3.54762226e-1f); // -0x1.6b46cap-2
        p = fmaf (p, x,  8.58785570e-1f); //  0x1.b7b2bep-1
        p = fmaf (p, x, -1.38065982e+0f); // -0x1.6172ecp+0
        p = fmaf (p, x,  5.97694337e-1f); //  0x1.3204fep-1
        float q =        1.03527203e-3f;  //  0x1.0f63eep-10
        q = fmaf (q, x, -7.35638570e-3f); // -0x1.e21bacp-8
        q = fmaf (q, x,  3.28683928e-2f); //  0x1.0d4204p-5
        q = fmaf (q, x, -3.79927397e-1f); // -0x1.850bb0p-2 
        q = fmaf (q, x,  6.86127126e-1f); //  0x1.5f4c0ep-1
        q = fmaf (q, x, -1.81509292e+0f); // -0x1.d0a9eep+0
        q = fmaf (q, x,  1.00000000e+0f); //  0x1.000000p+0
        r = (1.0f / q) * p;
        if (x < -15.0f) r = 1.0f;
        r = r * x * eh * eh;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Unfortunately, this accurate solution is achieved at the cost of a significant drop in performance. If one is willing to accept reduced accuracy while still achieving a smoothly decaying left tail, the following interpolation scheme, again based on $f(x) \approx x\exp(x)$, recovers much of the performance:

```c
__device__ float my_mishf (float x)
{
    float r;
    float e = expf (x);
    if (x >= -6.0625f) {
        r = 1.0f / fmaf (fmaf (-0.5f, e, -1.0f), e, -1.0f);
        r = fmaf (r, x, x);
    } else {
        r = fmaf (-0.5f, e, 1.0f);
        r = r * x * e;
    }
    return r;
}
```

As a machine-specific performance enhancement, `expf()` could be replaced by the device intrinsic `__expf()`.

Comment: Can you please check [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/5922#issuecomment-643592752)? Your version is quite slow when the input values are sampled from a uniform distribution `[-50, 50]`. The timings are the values reported by Nsight Compute. I wonder if that's the wrong way to benchmark code or if I have made a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Yashas I can't tell from that page which of the two versions you used: the first, fast one with accuracy comparable to your original reference, or the second version that improves accuracy for arguments < -1? The second one will be significantly slower (I am *guessing* half of the speed) for random data: there is lots more computation for negative arguments and a potentially divergent branch.

Comment: I used the second one.

Comment: @Yashas I would suggest including the first one if you are focused on performance. Clearly there is a trade-off here between performance and accuracy. I don't have any better ideas yet on how to achieve good accuracy in the negative half-plane without sacrificing performance. Should a stroke of genius strike me, I will happily update my answer, but this is the best I am able to do for now.

Comment: @Yashas I added a third solution based on a simple interpolation scheme which shifts the balance of accuracy and performance towards performance.

Comment: @njuffa Your rational approximation has a pole (denominator has a zero) at approximately 0.657882 and 7.9851.  How did you calculate the coefficients for it?

Comment: @ArmadilloJim The rational approximation is only used for arguments in the interval $[-15,-1]$. It was generated with a variant of the Remez algorithm and tested exhaustively for all `float` operands in the stated interval.

Answer (score 6):

With some algebraic manipulation (as pointed out in @orlp's answer), we can deduce the following:

$$f(x) = x \tanh(\log(1+e^x)) \tag{1}$$
$$ = x\frac{(1+e^x)^2 - 1}{(1+e^x)^2 + 1} = x\frac{e^{2x} + 2e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 2}\tag{2}$$
$$ = x - \frac{2x}{(1 + e^x)^2 + 1} \tag{3}$$

Expression $(3)$ works great when $x$ is negative with very little loss of precision. Expression $(2)$ is not suitable for large values of $x$ since the terms are going to blow up both in the numerator and denominator.

The function $(1)$ asymptotically hits zero as $x \to-\infty$. Now as $x$ becomes larger in magnitude, the expression $(3)$ will suffer from catastrophic cancellation: two large terms cancelling each other to give a really small number. The expression $(2)$ is more suitable in this range.

This works fairly well until $-18$ and beyond which you lose multiple significant figures.

Let's take a closer look at the function and try to approximate $f(x)$ as $x \to-\infty$.

$$f(x) = x \frac{e^{2x} + 2e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 2}$$

The  $e^{2x}$ will be orders of magnitude smaller than $e^x$. $e^x$ will be orders of magnitude smaller than $1$. Using these two facts, we can approximate $f(x)$ to:

$f(x) \approx x\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}\approx xe^x$

**Result:**

$f(x) \approx \begin{cases}
xe^x, & \text{if $x \le -18$} \\
x\frac{e^{2x} + 2e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 2} & \text{if $-18 \lt x \le -0.6$} \\
x - \frac{2x}{(1 + e^x)^2 + 1},  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $

**Fast CUDA implementation:**

```
__device__ float mish(float x)
{
    auto e = __expf(x);
    if (x <= -18.0f)
        return x * e;    

    auto n = e * e + 2 * e;
    if (x <= -0.6f)
        return x * __fdividef(n, n + 2);

    return x - 2 * __fdividef(x, n + 2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

An even more faster and accurate version:

$f(x) \approx \begin{cases}
x\frac{e^{2x} + 2e^x}{e^{2x} + 2e^x + 2} & \text{$x \le -0.6$} \\
x - \frac{2x}{(1 + e^x)^2 + 1},  & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 $

```
__device__ float mish(float x)
{
    auto e = __expf(value);
    auto n = e * e + 2 * e;
    if (value <= -0.6f)
        return value * __fdividef(n, n + 2);

    return value - 2 * __fdividef(value, n + 2);
}
```

Code: https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/8ad0cd3b30dbd0eb588c1f4c035db28c

Benchmarks with other implementations: https://github.com/YashasSamaga/ConvolutionBuildingBlocks/tree/master/mish

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} 
 & \text{Time (float)} & \text{Time (float4)} & \text{L2 norm of error vector} \\ \hline
\text{mish} & 1.49ms & 1.39ms & 2.4583e-05 \\ \hline
\text{relu} & 1.47ms & 1.39ms & \text{N/A} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to perform the logarithm. If you let $p = 1+\exp(x)$ then we have
$f(x) = x\cdot\dfrac{p^2-1}{p^2+1}$ or alternatively $f(x) = x - \dfrac{2x}{p^2+1}$.

Comment: This might not work great for large values of x. $p^2$ will blow up even for x = 10.

Comment: @Yashas The latter form has no issues with that. If that term blows up the function will be almost linear there anyway.

Comment: @Yashas I computed the error with the ground truth and for $x = 10$ it's $6\cdot 10^{-16}$, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have the impression someone just wanted a function that goes smoothly from 0.6x to very close to x, and played around with functions until they found something. I bet two pieces of a 2nd degree polynomial followed by f(x) = x will work just as well.

Comment: It's all zeros below x = -17 with this expression.

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that someone wanted to multiply x by a function f(x) that goes smoothly from 0 to 1, and experimented until they found an expression using elementary functions that did this, with no mathematical reason behind the choice of functions.

After choosing a parameter t, let $p_t(x) = 1/2 + (3 / 4t)x - x^3 / (4t^3)$, then $p_t(0) = 1/2$, $p_t(t) = 1$, $p_t(-t) = 0$, and $p_t'(t) = p_t'(-t) = 0$. Let g(x) = 0 if x < -t, 1 if x > +1, and $p_t(x)$ if -t ≤ x ≤ +t. This is a function that smoothly changes from 0 to 1. Choose another parameter s, and instead of f(x) calculate x * g (x - s).

t = 3.0 and s = -0.3 matches the given function quite reasonably and is calculated an awful lot faster (which seems important). It's different of course. As this function is used as a tool in some problem, I'd want to see a mathemtical reason why the original function is *better*.

Comment: You are quite right about your impression. If you are interested, this function was introduced in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08681). A closely related paper is for [swish](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05941). It was a search for rectifier like functions with a specific set of characteristics that tends to perform really well in deep learning tasks. However, it is required that any approximation approximates mish function relly well because the neural networks are trained to use mish and any arbitrary approximation that shows similar behaviour might not work as a replacement.

Comment: I didn't mention in the question but I was looking for a good approximation to accelerate neural network inference. I need to run trained models (which are trained with the exact form of mish) and I don't have control over the training. So I would need something that closely resembles and is really fast.

Answer (score 2):

The context [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17148) is computer vision and the activation function for training neural nets.

Chances are this code is going to be executed on a GPU.  While performance is going to depend on the distribution of typical inputs, *generally speaking it is important to avoid branches in GPU code*.  Warp divergence can significantly degrade performance of your code.  For example, the [CUDA Toolkit Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#control-flow) says:

> Note:High Priority: Avoid different execution paths within the same warp.
>   Flow control instructions (if, switch, do, for, while) can significantly affect the instruction throughput by causing threads of the same warp to diverge; that is, to follow different execution paths. If this happens, the different execution paths must be executed separately; this increases the total number of instructions executed for this warp.
>   ...
>   For branches including just a few instructions, warp divergence generally results in marginal performance losses. For example, the compiler may use predication to avoid an actual branch. Instead, all instructions are scheduled, but a per-thread condition code or predicate controls which threads execute the instructions. Threads with a false predicate do not write results, and also do not evaluate addresses or read operands.

### Two branch-free implementations

[OP's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/125052/122377) does have short branches so branch predication may happen with some compilers.  One other thing I noticed is that it appears to be acceptable to compute the exponential once per call.  That is, I understand OP's answer to say one call to the exponential is not "expensive" or "slow".

In that case, I would suggest the following simple code:

```
__device__ float mish(float x)
{
    float expx = __expf(x);
    return x / (1.0f + 2.0f / (expx * (2.0f + expx)));
}
```

It has no branches, one exponential, one multiplication, and two divisions.  Divisions are often more expensive than multiplications so I also tried out this code:

```
__device__ float mish(float x)
{
    float expx = __expf(x);
    float psi = expx * (2.0f + expx);
    return x * (psi / (2.0f + psi));
}
```

This has no branches, one exponential, two multiplications, and one division.

### Relative error

I computed the log10 relative accuracy of these two implementations plus OP's answer.  I computed over the interval (-100,100) with an increment of 1/1024, then computed a running maximum over 51 values (to reduce the visual clutter but still give the correct impression).  Computing the first implementation with double precision suffices as a reference.  The exponential is accurate to within one ULP, and there are only a handful of arithmetic operations; the rest of the bits are more than sufficient to make a table maker's dilemma very unlikely.  Thus we're very likely to be able to compute correctly rounded single-precision reference values.

[image: Log10 relative error]

Green: first implementation.  Red: second implemenation.  Blue: OP's implementation.  The blue and red overlap through most of their range (left of about -20).

Note to OP: you'll want to change the cutoff to greater than -5 if you want to maintain full precision.

### Performance

You'll have to test these two implementations to see which is faster.  They should be at least as fast as OP's, and I suspect they'll be much faster because of the lack of branches.  However, if they are not fast enough for you, there's more you can do.

#### An important question:

What is the distribution of typical input values you expect to see?  Are values going to be uniformly distributed over the entire range the function is effectively computable?  Or are they going to be clustered around 0 almost all the time?  If so, with what variance/spread?

#### The asymptotics can be improved.

On the left, OP uses `x * expx` with a cutoff of -18.  This cutoff can be increased to about -15.5625 with no loss of precision.  With the cost of one extra multiplication, you could use `x * expx * (1.0f - 0.5f * expx)` and a cutoff of about -4.875.  Note: the multiplication by 0.5 can be optimized to a subtraction of 1 from the exponent so I'm not counting that here.

On the right, you can introduce another asymptotic.  If `x > 8.75`, simply `return x`.  With a little more cost, you could do `x * (1.0f - 2.0f * __expf(-2.0f * x))` when `x > 6.0`.

#### Interpolation

For the center part of the range (-4.875, 6.0), you can use a table of interpolants.  If their ranges are equally spaced, you can use one division to compute a direct index into the table (without branching).  Calculating such a table would take some effort, but depending on your needs may be worth it: a handful of multiplies and adds *might* be less expensive than the exponential.  That said, the implementers of the exponential in the library probably have spent a lot of time and effort getting theirs correct and fast.  Also, the "mish" function doesn't present any opportunities for range reduction.